# Matlab: Using sym in limit

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Say I have the following symbolic function:

```
syms f(t)
f(t)=sin(t)/t
```

I want to get the limit using another symbolic function. I tried:

```
syms lim(x)
lim(x)=limit(f(t),t,x)
```

But when I tried to use `lim(0)` I got this error:

> Error using symengine (line 59)
>   Division by zero.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: I can not reproduce the error.

Comment: Sorry. It was `lim(0)` that gave the error. I corrected the post.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `lim(x)`. For some reason the `limit` is gone. I don't really understand what is going wrong there. If you use an anonymous function instead of a function handle, the evaluation of `limit` is postponed until x has a value and it works.

```
>> lim=@(x)limit(f(t),t,x)

lim = 

    @(x)limit(f(t),t,x)

>> lim(0)

ans =

1
```

Comment: `lim(x)` is not a function handle. It's a `symfun`, as is `f`, which does not delayed evaluation.

Comment: Thanks. This was my second choice. But I want to do it using symbolic functions. For one, I'll be able to pass a vector to `lim`.

Comment: @horchler: I would have expected some behaviour like you often see with `int` where the expression is not resolved. Those cases where the evaluation of `int(f)` is `int(f)`.

Comment: @Jerry: The `limit` function does not support vectors. You won't get that done.

Comment: No: `limit(x,[1,2,3])` results in `Error in MuPAD command: Limit point must be a scalar.`.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab does not have delayed assignments as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878959/can-you-perform-a-delayed-set-in-mathematica-in-matlab).  Therefore, when `lim` is created, the call to `limit` is immediately evaluated with `x` replacing `t`:

```
>> syms t x f(t) lim(x)
>> f(t) = sin(t)/t
f(t) =
sin(t)/t

>> lim(x) = limit(f(t),t,x)
lim(x) =
sin(x)/x
```

And when you evaluate `lim(0)`, you get `sin(0)/0`, which throws the error.

Comment: For the symbolic math toolbox there is something like delayed evaluation. Try for example `int(exp(sin(a^b + b^a*g)+a*3),a)`, here the `int` is not evaluated. I would expect the same behaviour with `sym/limit` which is called in this case.

Comment: @Daniel Not on my R2014b install.  `limit`, in this instance, does a direct substitution of variables although your `int` example does not.  I guess a more precise wording is "Matlab does not currently have a facility for explicit delayed evaluation though certain functions may exhibit the behavior".